# Place element's z-index above parent's sibling element

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a menu with two elements :

```
<nav id="menu">
            <div id="menu-list">
                <a href="{{ path('recipes') }}" class="menu-list-item menu-list-item-selected" id="menu-list-item-recipes">{{ 'recipes.tab.label'|trans }}</a>
                <a href="{{ path('ingredients') }}" class="menu-list-item" id="menu-list-item-ingredients">{{ 'ingredients.tab.label'|trans }}</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Both `<a>` elements are positionned relative and their parents (`#menu` and `#menu-list` aren't positionned)

On load of the page, there is a 50%-opaque black layer on the page that is a `#menu`'s sibling element :

```
<div id="blackLayer" onclick="hideBlackLayer()">
    </div>
```

#blackLayer is positionned fixed and has a z-index at 2.

I want, on the load of the page that one (and only one) of `.menu-list-item` elements (say the `#menu-lits-item-recipes`) to be above the dark layer.

If i set the `#menu-lits-item-recipes` z-index at 3, nothing happens. And if I set the `#menu`'s z-index at 3 (with `position: relative`) everything is above the dark layer.

Is there a way to make only one `<a>` over the dark layer without modifying DOM tree since I cannot change the HTML ?

Comment: the child is in a different stacking context to the parent sibling so you would need to position the parent and give that a higher z-index than it's sibling - [more info on stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).  If you are only wanting the anchor to be above the black, then you would have to do some js to move the link into the same context as the parent sibling or bring the menu to the from and give that a similar overlay that the link can then sit on top of

Comment: Yes, thank you ! (didn't think of giving the menu an overlay, that's the easiest way)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution which I created here.

https://jsfiddle.net/mc1ekzu4/37/

Note that I'm trying to simulate your case, but the key thing is you should have `position: relative;` for your highlighted element.

```
#blackLayer {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#menu-list-item-recipes {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```